# SQL Server query to find clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identity, clustered-index

Is it possible to write a query that returns all tables that have clustered indexes that are not based on an identity key?

Comment: You tried anything yet. The meta tables sys.indexes and sys.index_columns and sys.columns will be a place to start.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want all the tables that are not clustered on *only* the IDENTITY column, or all the tables that don't include the IDENTITY column anywhere in the clustered index?

Comment: Aaron, I guess what I'm interested in is any clustered index that is not solely an identity key

Answer (score 17):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    TableName = t.name, 
    ClusteredIndexName = i.name,
    ColumnName = c.Name
FROM
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON i.index_id = ic.index_id AND i.object_id = ic.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON ic.column_id = c.column_id AND ic.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    i.index_id = 1  -- clustered index
    AND c.is_identity = 0
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM sys.columns c2 
                WHERE ic.object_id = c2.object_id AND c2.is_identity = 1)
```

OK, this query will list those primary keys that have a column which is *not* identity, but where there's also additionally a second column in the primary key constraint that **IS** an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Marc, no I thing I'd like to know those clustered indexes which were composed of an identity key and something else

Comment: @DevilDog: updated my response - should be handling your requirements now

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT  s.name AS schema_name, o.name AS object_name, i.name AS index_name
FROM    sys.indexes i
JOIN    sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
JOIN    sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE   i.type = 1 -- Clustered index
--AND       o.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- Uncomment if you want to see only user objects
AND     NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    sys.index_columns ic INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE   ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    AND     c.is_identity = 1 -- Is identity column
)
ORDER BY schema_name, object_name, index_name;
```

Sample output (AdventureWorks2008R2):

```
schema_name    object_name                 index_name
-------------- --------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------
HumanResources Employee                    PK_Employee_BusinessEntityID
HumanResources EmployeeDepartmentHistory   PK_EmployeeDepartmentHistory_BusinessEntityID_StartDate_DepartmentID
HumanResources EmployeePayHistory          PK_EmployeePayHistory_BusinessEntityID_RateChangeDate
Person         BusinessEntityAddress       PK_BusinessEntityAddress_BusinessEntityID_AddressID_AddressTypeID
Person         BusinessEntityContact       PK_BusinessEntityContact_BusinessEntityID_PersonID_ContactTypeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you all the user tables, columns, data type, and if the column is part of cluster index it will return column's sequence/order in the crusted index otherwise it will return NULL.

```
SELECT U.name [OWNER],O.name [TABLE_NAME],C.name [COLUMN_NAME],T.name [DATA_TYPE],C.length [DATA_LENGTH], x.keyno [Primary_Key_order]
FROM syscolumns C
inner  join sysobjects O on O.Id=C.Id and o.xtype='U' -- User Tables
inner join sysusers U on O.Uid=U.UID
inner join systypes T on C.xtype=T.xtype
left outer join (Select O.name [TABLE_NAME] , C.name [COLUMN_NAME], IK.keyno
            from syscolumns C
            inner  join sysobjects O on O.Id=C.Id and O.xtype='U' -- User Tables
            join sysindexkeys IK on O.id=IK.ID  and C.colid=IK.COLID and Indid=1 -- Only Clustered Index
            ) x 
            on x.TABLE_NAME=O.name and X.COLUMN_NAME=C.name
order by U.name
```